# Visual Studio 2012 does not generate moc files

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, moc

I am using Qt V5.1.0 and Qt-Addin 1.2.2 for visual studio 2012.

I have two project in the solution called "Brain" and "GUI". "Brain" is defined as Utility project and "GUI" as an Application project. I added "Brain" as a reference for "GUI".

When I use one class of "Brain" project into "GUI" cpp file. I get link errors telling me that there are unresolved external symbols. Moreover, there are no moc files into the "Generated Files" folder.

I tried to clean the solution but it does not work. I also tried to remove "Generated Files" folder into explorer and visual studio but without any results. I tried to find a solution with google but one worked for me.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Do you use a build rule to create the moc'ed files? (I'm not familiar with the Qt-Addin, so I don't know whether it takes care of generating the moc files.)

Comment: The addin is supposed to do that (make build rules for rcc, moc ..). Although since I use CMake to generate my Visual Studio projects instead of the addin functionality I can not help debugging the addin..

Comment: this link helped me http://vperi.com/2012/04/23/automatic-mocing-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the [moc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/moc.html) as part of the build and include the resulting c++ source as files that need compiling

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I solved the problem by myself. It is not a moc issue. I just had to change Brain settings from "Utility Project" to "Static Library (.lib)" and now it worked ! Moc are generated and there is no linking problem. Thank you again !